Natural deduction in coq: implication introduction
I am working upon the same problem as the person from this question. I finished the proof given in the answer. According to the definition of the theorem from the logics book that I am reading ("Introduction into Logics" by Markin, Bocharov ISBN 978-5-8199-0365-0 in Russian): a theorem is the last formula in a deduction constructed from an empty set of assumptions.
Here is the paper proof from the initial question:

Section ProofOfEx13.
 Variables p q r : Prop. 
 Hypothesis H : p /\ q -> r.
 
 Theorem Ex13: p -> q -> r. 
 Proof. 
    intros Hp Hq. 
    specialize (conj Hp Hq) as Hconj.
    specialize (H Hconj) as Hr.
    exact Hr.
  Qed. 

End ProofOfEx13.

Here is the proof state before the last tactic execution exact Hr..
1 goal
p, q, r : Prop
H : p /\ q -> r
Hp : p
Hq : q
Hconj : p /\ q
Hr : r
______________________________________(1/1)
r

Is it possible to construct an object p -> q -> r both in the context and in the result and then do exact? So we could get rid of all the assumptions in the context and get the exact formula that we were required to prove? I understand that we have constructed exactly this term (p -> q -> r) as a function, I know how to use Show Proof, but how to show this to a person who knows only the paper proofs?

There are several questions in your answer, please only ask one (and create a new question for the next ones). Also, please give the title, author, and link to/ISBN/something unique about the book you say to be following.

@JoJoModding I added the title and the ISBN, but the book is in Russian.


So we could get rid of all the assumptions in the context and get the exact formula that we were required to prove?

The short answer is no:  You could use revert to get assumptions back into the conclusion, but (and before that) all you could do to get the same in the context is an assert (G : p -> q -> r) and then you are back to square one...
That said, I'd think your proof is actually fine:  In natural deduction we go from just the premises to the conclusion, and may "introduce assumptions" and eventually have to "discharge them", while in Coq we work with the whole sequent to begin with.  In particular, instead of "introducing assumptions", we intros from the conclusion (and only from the conclusion).  That considered, a way to think about a correspondence might be: just before the last exact you are in fact at line 5 of the natural deduction proof, and the last exact is doing in one last step all the "discharging".
That might be enough for "showing to a person who knows only the paper proofs".  For a slightly more controlled approach, i.e. to (or maybe short of) a so called shallow embedding, you could skip importing the standard Coq prelude (see the -noinit option) and create a little set of tactics that mimics the rules of natural deduction (only forward reasoning and to the point that it can be done, see the previous paragraphs), to make the correspondence more stringent and apparent, e.g. for use in the classroom.

We can think that coq uses the deduction metatheorem: (Γ, A |- B) implies (Γ |- A -> B).

Well, I guess it's more that we are using that meta-theorem when doing revert, and its converse when doing intros, and it's still just a figure of speech: not only Coq is way beyond just propositional or predicate logic, it's a dependently-typed functional language, where tactics are "just" meta-programming, what we eventually build is terms, i.e. terms that must type-check.  Indeed it's not about inference rules, it's about typing rules: https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.20.0/refman/language/cic.html
